# How to serve static contents in WildFly 26.0.1?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I was using the following web.xml config to serve static files using the default servlet in tomcat and jetty.

```xml
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/favicon.ico</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However, when it comes to WildFly, all static files cannot be found by the server.  So, how should I config WildFly to serve static files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it seems the wildfly server does not register "default servlet" for you.  To use it, you need to register the servlet class yourself.  Since wildfly uses undertow, the class is `io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet`.

**Complete web.xml:**

```xml
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>resolve-against-context-root</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/favicon.ico</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: For reference, what is the benefit of using this instead of just having Wildfly serve this normally?  That is, I have a JAX-RS service that has some web services and some static React and "normal" content.  I don't need to configure anything to get this to work.  Is there a performance difference using the default servlet?